How can I make the material edges smoother on a PBR terrain?
I'm using HillHeightMap to generate a heightmap. I found a way to generate an alphamap based on a heightmap.
This is how I create the material
/** Add texture into the red layer  */
val red: Texture = assetManager.loadTexture(redTexturePath)
red.setWrap(WrapMode.Repeat)
material.setTexture("AlbedoMap_0", red)
material.setTexture(
    "NormalMap_0",
    assetManager.loadTexture(redTextureNormalPath)
)
material.setFloat("AlbedoMap_0_scale", 64f)

/** Add texture into the green layer */
val green: Texture = assetManager.loadTexture(greenTexturePath)
green.setWrap(WrapMode.Repeat)
material.setTexture("AlbedoMap_1", green)
material.setTexture(
    "NormalMap_1",
    assetManager.loadTexture(greenTextureNormalPath)
)
material.setFloat("AlbedoMap_1_scale", 32f)

/** Add texture into the blue layer */
val blue: Texture = assetManager.loadTexture(blueTexturePath)
blue.setWrap(WrapMode.Repeat)
material.setTexture("AlbedoMap_2", blue)
material.setTexture(
    "NormalMap_2",
    assetManager.loadTexture(blueTextureNormalPath)
)
material.setFloat("AlbedoMap_2_scale", 128f)
HillHeightMap.NORMALIZE_RANGE = 100f

This is how I generate the alphamap
private var alphamap: WeakReference<Image>? = null
private var rendered: Boolean = false

private val tex1Height = 0f
private val tex2Height = 75f
private val tex3Height = 80f
private val maxHeight = 300f

if (rendered && alphamap != null && alphamap?.get() != null) return alphamap!!.get()!!

val height = heightmap.size
val width = heightmap.size

val data = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(width * height * 4)

for (x in 0 until width) {
    for (z in 0 until height) {
        var alpha = 255
        var red = 0
        var green = 0
        var blue = 0

        val pointHeight = heightmap.getScaledHeightAtPoint(z, width-(x + 1))

        if (pointHeight < maxHeight) {
            if (pointHeight > tex3Height) blue = 255
            else if (pointHeight > tex2Height) green = 255
            else if (pointHeight > tex1Height) red = 255
            else if (pointHeight < tex1Height) alpha = 0
        } else alpha = 0
        data
            .put(red.toByte())
            .put(green.toByte())
            .put(blue.toByte())
            .put(alpha.toByte())
    }
}

val image = Image(Image.Format.RGBA8, width, height, data)
alphamap = WeakReference(image)
rendered = true
return image

How can I make the transition between textures smoother/less noticeable?

I updated the code in response to @DMGregory comment. It seemed to adjust the alignment of the textures but still not quite right.
blue = ((pointHeight - tex3Height) * 10f).coerceIn(0f, 255f)


blue = ((pointHeight - tex3Height) * 1000000f).coerceIn(0f, 255f)



Unfortunately, when you're blending all the way from 0 to 255 over the span of a single texel, as you're doing here, the grid shape of those texels becomes quite obvious. Does your use case permit using a wider / softer blending zone, something like blue = ((pointHeight - tex3height) * blendSteepness).coerceIn(0, 255) (and corresponding gradients for your other texture layers)?

Yes I will give this a try and see what happens.

@DMGregory I updated the question with the result. I also tried .000000001f and it was just all white to the end of the landscape.

What were you doing with red/green/alpha? The blend from white to brown is the one you want to look at for the blue component, and that one looks quite smooth for the 10f case from the sliver we can see in the screenshot.

No I tried it with only one value to see what happened I will try it with all channels and see what happens.
